# Angular - showing value without submit

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using Angular 12. I have a modal and I am updating with this modal. When I type a value in the input of the modal, it shows the value without click the submit button. It doesn't update the value but it shows. I don't want this. Do not update the value without clicking submit. What am I missing?

**profile.component.ts**

```js
updateForm!: FormGroup;
userProfiles = new UserProfile

ngOnInit(): void {

  this.username = this.router.snapshot.params['username']
  this.router.params.subscribe(params => {
    this.username = params['username'];
    this.getOne(); 
});

  this.updateForm= new FormGroup({
    name:  new FormControl(''),
    user_info: new FormControl('')
  });
}

getOne(){
  this.dataService.getProfile(this.username).pipe(
    map(resp => [resp])
   ).subscribe(res=>{(
     this.playerData = res,
     this.userProfiles = this.playerData[0])
   })
}

updateProfile(){
  
  this.dataService.updateProfile(this.userProfiles).subscribe(re=>{
    $("#editProfile").modal("hide");
  })
}
```

**profile.component.html**

```html
<h4 class="text-primary mb-0">{{item.name }}</h4>

<div class="modal fade" id="editProfile" >
   .
   .
   .
   <form class="comment-form"  [formGroup]="updateForm" id="editProfileForm" >
       <input type="text" class="form-control"   formControlName="name" [(ngModel)]="userProfiles.name" >
       <button type="submit" (click)="updateProfile()" >Save</button>

   </form>
   .
   .
   .

</div>
```

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean - but you really don’t want to combine NgModel with reactive forms (formControlName)

Answer (score 0):

You have several problem

Your first problem obviously comes from this part =>

```
[(ngModel)]="userProfiles.name"
```

Basicaly, you are telling angular to adopt a two way binding on "userProfiles.name" field.

To fix the problem,

1- Remove [(ngModel)]="userProfiles.name"

2- Set initial state of your form:

```
getOne(){
  this.dataService.getProfile(this.username).pipe(
    map(resp => [resp])
   ).subscribe(res=>{(
     this.playerData = res,
     this.userProfiles = this.playerData[0])
     this.updateForm= new FormGroup({
       name:  new FormControl(this.userProfiles?.name),
       user_info: new FormControl(/*whatever field that should be binded */)
     });
   })
}
```

Your second problem is you are using a form then not using it in your update action.

3- You should be sending data coming from your form, not from your original object:

```
  this.dataService.updateProfile(this.updateForm.value).subscribe(re=>{
    $("#editProfile").modal("hide");
  })
```

4- Once your update has been done and confirmed, NOW only you should update the orignial value coming from your getOne() method =>

```
updateProfile(){

  this.dataService.updateProfile(this.updateForm.value).subscribe(re => {
    $("#editProfile").modal("hide");
    // If re is the updated user, i suggest doing something like:
    // this.userProfiles.name = re

    // If is not the case, i suggest doing something like:
    // this.userProfiles.name = this.updateForm.controls.name.value
  })
}
```

Comment: not working. getting error in console when I remove `[(ngModel)]="userProfiles.name"`.